# How can i write automation code in appium to test facebook login by mobile app?

Tags: automated-testing, appium, android, uiautomation

I have an Android mobile app. which provides facility to login in this app using Facebook but while automating this page, I'm not able to tap continue button which comes after entering username and password.

[image: image of fb log in]

I'm using below xpath to find the continue button.

```
@AndroidFindBy(xpath= "//android.widget.Button[@content-desc=\"Continue\"]")
```

Can someone help me. how do find it appropriately ?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is calling an activity within the Facebook application. Your driver, therefore, doesn't know how to interact with it. In order to tell it how to, you need to find the package/ID of the activity that is called and set it as an "appWaitActivity" capability.

I have to do similar within my app to call an MS login activity. The Java code looks like the following:

```
capabilities.setCapability("appWaitActivity", "com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationActivity");
```